# In Powershell, how can I get the US cultureinfo (en-US) to display as mm/DD/yyyy with 2 decimal places when the month and date are less than 9?

Tags: date, powershell, format, cultureinfo

How can I get the US cultureinfo (en-US) to display as mm/DD/yyyy with 2 decimal places when the month and date are equal to or less than 9? I want to display a date as 09/03/2012 instead of 9/3/2012? Please explain how it works as well as providing an exact answer. Thank you!

```
[void] [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.Windows.Forms")
[void] [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.Drawing") 

$objForm = New-Object Windows.Forms.Form 

$objForm.Text = "Select a Date" 
$objForm.Size = New-Object Drawing.Size @(190,190) 
$objForm.StartPosition = "CenterScreen"

$objForm.KeyPreview = $True

$objForm.Add_KeyDown({
    if ($_.KeyCode -eq "Enter") 
        {
            $dtmDate=$objCalendar.SelectionStart
            $objForm.Close()
        }
    })

$objForm.Add_KeyDown({
    if ($_.KeyCode -eq "Escape") 
        {
            $objForm.Close()
        }
    })

$us = New-Object system.globalization.cultureinfo("en-US")

$objCalendar = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.MonthCalendar
$objCalendar.ShowTodayCircle = $False
$objCalendar.MaxSelectionCount = 1
$objForm.Controls.Add($objCalendar) 

$objForm.Topmost = $True

$objForm.Add_Shown({$objForm.Activate()})  
[void] $objForm.ShowDialog() 

$finaldate = $dtmdate | Get-Date -format ($us.DateTimeFormat.ShortDatePattern) 

Write-Host $finaldate
```

Answer (score 1):

You simply have to use the correct DateTime format string e.g.:

```
C:\PS> Get-Date -Format MM/dd/yyyy -Month 9 -Day 3
09/03/2012
```

See the MSDN topic on [Custom DateTime Formatting Strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx).